Botframework on Microsoft-Teams: Attachments with special characters lost when uploaded from Microsoft Teams
I'm using BotFramework in C# (.NET 8). The issue I'm encountering is that when I upload an attachment from Teams with certain characters, such as a '+', the attachment "disappears" when received in the bot's backend.
For example, if I upload a file with a "normal" name like test.txt, I receive this in the bot's backend:
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.file.download.info",
            "content": {
                "downloadUrl": "https://ckm-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxxxx/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx&Translate=false&tempauth=v1.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx&ApiVersion=2.0",
                "uniqueId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
                "fileType": "txt"
            },
            "contentUrl": "https://ckm-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxxxxx/Documents/Microsoft Teams Chat Files/test.txt",
            "name": "test.txt"
        },
        {
            "contentType": "text/html",
            "content": ""
        }
    ],
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2024-07-11T10:29:11.4680572Z",
    "localTimestamp": "2024-07-11T12:29:11.4680572+02:00",
    "id": "1720693751445",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    // ....
}

However, if I upload a file with a name like test+.txt, I receive only this:
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "text/html",
            "content": ""
        }
    ],
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2024-07-11T10:36:45.0287287Z",
    "localTimestamp": "2024-07-11T12:36:45.0287287+02:00",
    "id": "1720694205007",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    //...
}

This issue occurs with the basic example from BotBuilder-Samples (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments).
Code Handling Attachments
Here is the code I am using to handle the attachments in my bot:
if (turnContext.Activity.Attachments != null && turnContext.Activity.Attachments.Any())
{
    foreach (var file in turnContext.Activity.Attachments)
    {
        // Process each attachment
        var fileType = file.ContentType;
        var fileName = file.Name;
        var fileUrl = file.ContentUrl;

        // Logging for debugging
        Console.WriteLine($"Received file: {fileName} ({fileType}) at {fileUrl}");
    }
}

Attempts to Resolve

I reviewed the settings in the manifest generated for Teams (manifest schema), but didn't find anything related to URL encoding or handling special characters in attachment names.

Question
Is there a known issue with handling attachments that contain special characters in their names in BotFramework? If so, how can I handle these attachments correctly? Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
